# KSOAP webservices in android

Tags: android, ksoap2

I am using the following code:

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            envelope.dotNet=true;           
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);  
            try
            {
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);              
                SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                Log.i("myApp", response.toString());  
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText("message="+response.toString());
                setContentView(tv);                              
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The webservice in working properly,but it shows following error:

W/System.err(975):    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@44f1adb8
 W/System.err(975):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:116)
 W/System.err(975):     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:137)
 W/System.err(975):     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:63)
 W/System.err(975):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:100)
 W/System.err(975):     at com.redbus.SearchRoute.onCreate(SearchRoute.java:90)
 W/System.err(975):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
 W/System.err(975):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
 W/System.err(975):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
 W/System.err(975):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
 W/System.err(975):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
 W/System.err(975):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 W/System.err(975):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 W/System.err(975):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
 W/System.err(975):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 W/System.err(975):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 W/System.err(975):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
 W/System.err(975):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
 W/System.err(975):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: have you added the ksoap2 library to ur project?

Comment: I have added that file..himanshu

Comment: post ur URL,MTHOD_NAME and SOAP_ACTION here...

Comment: try using SoapObject instead of SoapPrimitive.

Answer (score 0):

According to `faultstring: 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request.` I think ksoap is receiving a response that is not a valid XML soap response.

It seems that your webservice is returning Object reference exception. do you send correct parameters to your webservice?

check and correct them in `request` object.

Comment: can you paste lines of code that you initialize request object?

Answer (score 0):

My SOAP call goes as follows, I think you are omitting the namespace.

```
List respHeaders = httpTransport.call(NAMESPACE+"/"+methodName, envelope, headerPropertyList);
```

Comment: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/comment
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/answer

Answer (score 0):

This Code works for try it :) in the url use 10.0.2.2 not 10.0.2.1 cause the emulator is using this port and in the request.addProperty you must specify the method name as you wrote it in the Web Service ex : my method was taking a string m so I wrote in the addProperty("m","//here the object you want to send")

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://tempuri.org/", "GetCoursesInfos");
    request.addProperty("m","courses");

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet=true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


    HttpTransportSE http = new HttpTransportSE("http://10.0.2.2:2612/Service1.svc");//hint you

        http.call("http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetCoursesInfos", envelope);

        Object result= (Object)envelope.getResponse();
        message=result.toString();



    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("1", "first exe");
        txt.setText(e.getMessage());

    }
```